# 2 вёрстки для разных устройств нужно выложить на хостинг

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, mobile-web, adaptive-design

Что делать, если вёрстка для мобилок очень отличается от других размеров (десктопа, планшета и т.д.). Заказчик решил сделать для мобилок совсем другой сайт, но как разместить 2 разных сайта на одном адресе, чтобы для каждого устройства открывался соответствующий.

P.S. про медиа запросы знаю, они не могут, сайты действительно очень разные.

Пока что из идей у меня только сделать 2 блока, в них поместить вёрстки 2 разных сайтов и сделать медиа запрос для каждого, но это кажется неправильным.

Comment: Очевидно, отслеживать user-agent и по результату отдавать нужную версию

Comment: Выводил через медиа, когда сталкивался. Читал, что так не должно быть и функционал и конструкция должны быть похожи между моб и десктоп версиями, но может я не прав.

Comment: Есть такой метод, который называется **RESS** (_Responsive Design + Server Side_). Определяете на стороне сервера устройство (для этого часто используют http://mobiledetect.net/) и отдаёте те или иные шаблоны. Как и в любом другом способе, тут есть и свои плюсы, и минусы. Если дизайн кардинально отличается для мобильных устройств и десктопов, то RESS вполне уместен. Кроме того, это позволяет еще и выдавать только требуемые CSS и JS, избегая излишеств. В то же время, надо учесть, что объём работы вы себе увеличите раза в два, верстая одну и ту же страницу под разные устройства.

Answer (score 1):

Мобильную версию выложить на поддомен и использовать теги `<link>` для указания различных URL с атрибутами `rel="canonical"` и `rel="alternate"`.

Подробнее об этом читайте на сайте [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls?hl=ru#annotation-in-the-html). Получится именно так, как вам надо. Замечу, однако, что использовать данную технику - это прошлый век, а продвигать такие сайты мучительно долго и дорого. Легче заново переписать код под адаптивную верстку. Но заказчику конечно виднее :)

Answer (score 1):

По правильному лучше всего использовать стили css для отображения той или иной вёрстки в зависимости от разрешения экрана:
@media (max-width: 1024px){display:...}
Соответственно разместить обе вёрстки на одной странице и регулировать стилем которая из них будет отображаться

Answer (score 1):

Первое что пришло в голову - обернуть разные "страницы" и показывать их в зависимости от ширины экрана.

```
<div class="maxWidth1980">
Тут контент для декстопа
</div>

<div class="maxWidth768">
Тут контент для мобилы
</div>

<style>
.maxWidth768{
display:none;
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
.maxWidth1980{
display:none;
}
.maxWidth768{
display:block;
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: Так и делаю, по-другому не получилось :(

Comment: Это действительно правильный вариант решений?

Comment: Я прав, что таком случае пользователю придется загружать две вёрстки в независимости от версии?

Comment: Да, страница будет весить больше. Из минусов - немного сложнее верстать и писать страничные скрипты. Из плюсов - это очень простое решение и можно будет сделать переключение на полную версию одной кнопкой без перезагрузки страницы

Answer (score 0):

в общем случае задача решается следующим образом:

1. анализ разрешения
2. выдача соответствующей верстки // может быть и редирект на другой сайт

упрощенно, если делать сайт на Вордпрессе, есть готовые плагины, позволяющие переключать темы в зависимости от разрешения // настраиваемого

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Нужно сделать без WP, можете, пожалуйста, конкретнее объяснить, как/с помощью каких технологий делать анализ разрешения и выдачу соответствующей вёрстки? Буду очень благодарен, если направите

Comment: @Виктор разрешение проверить на фронтэнде, по другому не получится (вы же планшеты не хотите переправлять?) потом заводите сессию или с куками гоняйте флаг какое устройство. Если используются шаблонизаторы, в зависимости от сохраненного состояния меняйте директорию шаблонов. Но если вообще у вас не только шаблоны, но и вся бизнеслогика другая, то переводите на поддомен и юзайте два отдельных сайта в принципе.

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно сделать [подключив JQuery](http://w3.org.ua/jquery/podklyuchenie-biblioteki-jquery-4-sposoba) к вашей основной верстке:
2. Добавить скрипт на страницу:

   ```
   $( window ).resize(function() {
          checkPosition();
   });
   $( window ).ready(function () {
          checkPosition();
   });
        function checkPosition() {
           if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1200px)').matches) {
               window.location.replace("http://ваша_верстка_для_мобильных")
            }
   ```
3. `max-width` укажите тот, который нужен в вашем случае.

Comment: Нет, допустим я использую samsung... на который нельзя установить оперу-мини4 и вся твоя кросбраузерность улетучилась... здесь проблемма уровня сервера (для кросбраузерности), и яп  для современно-ориентированной кросбраузерности. Яваскрипт здесь абсолютно не уместен, более того он вреден.

Comment: Я попробую это решение завтра, если получится баллы ваши. Не понял комментарий к ответу, почему кроссбраузерность улетучилась?

Comment: @Ilya Dyadkov отличное решение. а без jquery слабо?

Comment: @ganz что-то мне подстказывает, что целевой аудиторией приложения не являются обладатели самсунгов на которые не ставится опера мини :)

Comment: @muturgan верно, но около года-двух назад был вынужден исспользовать оный... Знаешь сколько сайтов открылись, не считая гугла? их url на вечно вбит в мой мозг.

Comment: @ganz не понял смысл вашего комментария. сформулирую по другому. мне грустно, что народ не в состоянии найти объект window и навесить на него обработчик на событие resize без использования jquery

Answer (score 0):

Элементарная проблемма: если в куках\гетах\субдоменах не указана версия wap\wml\pda\web то перенаправляем пользователя на страницу определения (либо в ядре цмс запускаем функцию), которая переадресует пользователя както так mysite.dot/pda/index.php \ mysite/index.php?version=pda \ pda.mysite/index.php либо изменит переменную $path_tempelate='pda'. Вариант с переадресацией не хорош так как у некоторых может стоять запрет отслеживания и ты не увидишь реферер, что все убъёт все переходы с гугла. Так же рекомендую версию определять не по браузеру и оси, а по размеру экрана+ учти что мобильная версия должна быть очень лёгкой: 100кб на страницу максимум(ибо с мобилы не всегда вайфай).

Answer (score -2):

Вам нужно в главном файле `index.php` сделать проверку устройства пользователя, и в соответствии с результатом перенаправить юзера на нужную версию сайта.
Сами версии для разных устроойств розкидайте по разным папкам:

```
/mobile/
/pc/
index.php
```

А в  `index.php` добавьте код проверки устройства:

```
function isMobile() { 

return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
}

if(isMobile()){
    header("Location: /mobile/"); // переход на моб версию
}
else { 
header("Location: /pc/"); // переход на пк версию
 }
```

Comment: не надо никаких редиректов. адекватные сайты используют какие-либо шаблонизаторы, все что надо сделать - изменить директорию шаблонов или тем.

Comment: ваш вариант кстати будет редиректить все андройды, хотя в намерения автора не входит редирект планшетов.